# Searching for attribute in an Array of Class Objects - Java

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am a newbie at this Java coding thing you guys all know and love so I have a few very basic and amateurish questions.

First off, the purpose of the program I am creating is to read a file of a list of employees from a file and put each employee object (with 7 attribute) into one part of my "emps" array.

My issue is that I don't know how to search through the array and display only SPECIFIC ATTRIBUTES one at a time.

For example, if someone wants a list of the salaries of all employees who are in a certain division (both attributes) how can use the search from the user input and output the salaries? Would I have to make arrays for each attribute and search through those?

This is what part of my file looks like with the employee attributes listed out in this order: Division Name, The # of Employees in the Division, Last Name, First Name, Years in Company, Salary, Status (active or retired) and  Section of work.

`Occupational
14
Daley   Richie      3   5678.54     a   Atomic Waste
Blago   Donald      14  2367.00     a   Public Relations
Smith   John        15  32400.40    a   Public Relations
Bush    Jorge       6   11004.45    a   Atomic Waste
Gore    Alvin       37  119003.45   r   Public Relations
Ryan    Ryan        4   111000.00   a   Human Resources
Hanrath Jon     6   63452.22    a   Public Relations
Jones   Amanda      13  9222.34     a   Staff Concerns
Nader   Raul        23  21290.67    r   Human Resources
Alexander   Sheila      12  25111.89    a   Atomic Waste
Thompson    Bess        34  133292.89   r   Public Relations
Schwarzenegger  Cindy       27  133292.90   r   Human Resources
Allen   Ethan       30  30343.44    a   Staff Concerns
Stewart Martha      17  172348.00   r   Public Relations`

This is how my main method currently looks like:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class useHamayelSajaEmployee 
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for reading from keyboard


        File file = new File("empList.txt");
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file); //scanner for reading from file

        String divisionTitle = scan2.nextLine(); 
        int numOfEmps;

        final int MAX_EMPLOYEES = 1000;
        HamayelSajaEmployee []emps = new HamayelSajaEmployee[MAX_EMPLOYEES]; 

        for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++) //for loop to set all the objects in array to constructor values
                    {
                        emps [k] = new HamayelSajaEmployee();
                    }

        int lastCount = 0; 

            while(!divisionTitle.equals("END_OF_FILE"))
        {
            System.out.println(divisionTitle + '\n');
            numOfEmps = scan2.nextInt();

            for (int i = lastCount; i < numOfEmps + lastCount; i++) //instead of starting from the 0 point and writing over the objects in array, starting from point we stopped with lastCount
            {
                HamayelSajaEmployee emp1 = new HamayelSajaEmployee();

                emp1.SetDivisionTitle(divisionTitle);

                String lastName = scan2.next();
                System.out.print(lastName + "\t" ); 
                emp1.SetLastName(lastName);

                String firstName = scan2.next();
                System.out.print(firstName + "\t");
                emp1.SetFirstName(firstName);

                int yearsInCompany = scan2.nextInt();
                System.out.print(yearsInCompany + "\t" );
                emp1.SetYearsInCompany(yearsInCompany);

                double salary = scan2.nextDouble();
                System.out.print(salary + "\t"  + "\t" );
                emp1.SetSalary(salary);

                String status = scan2.next();
                char status1 = status.charAt(0);
                System.out.print(status1 + "\t" );
                emp1.SetStatus(status1);

                String section = scan2.nextLine();
                System.out.println(section);
                emp1.SetSection(section);


                //System.out.println(emp1.toString());
                emps [i]= emp1;

            }
            System.out.println('\n'); //prints extra line between divisions for clarity
            divisionTitle = scan2.next();
            lastCount = numOfEmps + lastCount;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        { 
            if(!emps[i].GetDivisionTitle().equals("noDivsionTitle"))//so that no empty slots in array print
            {System.out.println(emps[i]);}
        }

        System.out.print("Enter 'M' to go to the Menu or 'Q' to Quit");
        String newPlace = scan.next();
        char newPlace1 = newPlace.charAt(0);


        if(newPlace1 == 'M' || newPlace1 == 'm')
        {menu();}

        if (newPlace1 == 'Q' || newPlace1 == 'q')
        {finalStats();}

        else
            {
            while (!(newPlace1 == 'M' || newPlace1 == 'm' || newPlace1 == 'Q' || newPlace1 == 'q'))
                {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            System.out.println("Please try again.");

            System.out.print("Enter 'M' to go to the Menu or 'Q' to Quit");
            newPlace = scan.next();
            newPlace1 = newPlace.charAt(0);
            if(newPlace1 == 'M' || newPlace1 == 'm')
            {menu();}

            if (newPlace1 == 'Q' || newPlace1 == 'q')
            {finalStats();}
                }
            }

    }
```

I have a few methods that I need to write for searching and listing different attributes:

```
 public static void menu()

    {

        int countListAll = 0;
        int countEmployeeReport = 0;
        int countDivisionReport = 0;
        int countSalaryReport = 0;
        int countRetirementReport = 0;
        int countMain = 0;

        System.out.println("You have accessed Menu()");
        System.out.println("Enter 'L' for list of the employee data available. \nEnter 'E' to dislpay information on a particular employee. \nEnter 'D' to display division information. \nEnter 'S' to display salary information. \nEnter 'R' to display retirement information. \nEnter 'Q' to quit Menu and return to Main.");      
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String first = scan.next();
        char first1 = first.charAt(0);

        if (first1 == 'L'|| first1 =='l'||first1 =='E'||first1 =='e'||first1 =='D'||first1 =='d'||first1 =='S'||first1 =='s'||first1 =='R'||first1 =='r'||first1 =='Q'||first1 =='q')
        {
            switch (first1)
                {
            case 'L':
            case 'l':
            listAll();
            countListAll++;
            break;

            case 'E':
            case 'e':
            employeeReport();
            countEmployeeReport++;
            break;

            case 'D':
            case 'd':
            divisionReport();
            countDivisionReport++;
            break;

            case 'S':
            case 's':
            salaryReport();
            countSalaryReport++;
            break;

            case 'R':
            case 'r':
            retirementReport();
            countRetirementReport++;
            break;

            case 'Q':
            case 'q':
            countMain++;
            break;

                }
        }

        else 
            {menu();}
    }

    public static boolean listAll()
    {
        /*list all the employees names, years in company, salaries, statuses, and sections as read in from file*/
        System.out.println("You have accessed listAll()");
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean employeeReport()
    {
        /*prompts user to search last name and search through data read in from file and print division, last name, first name, and section from any line that matches (HOW DO YOU NOT PRINT EVERYTHING?)*/
        System.out.println("You have accessed employeeReport()");
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean divisionReport()
    {
        /*prompts user to search for a division or say "all" and display only ACTIVE employees ('a' for status) in that division by last name, first name, years in company and salary. Also displays the total salaries and the average salary in the division. (HOW WOULD YOU TAKE ONLY ONE ATTRIBUTE OUT OF EVERY SINGLE OBJECT?)*/
        System.out.println("You have accessed divisionReport()");
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean salaryReport()
    {
        /*prompts user to search for last name or "all" and displays each employee that matches last name with their salary*/
        System.out.println("You have accessed salaryReport()");
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean retirementReport()
    {
        /* prompts user to search for a retirement status ('a' or 'r') or "all". For each matching status, the employee last name, first name and status displayed. If 'r' then pension for each employee (depending on years in company and salary with specific formula) displayed*/
        System.out.println("You have accessed retirementReport()");
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean finalStats()
    {
        /*Displays number of times each menu letter was entered by the user. the output should display the number of times each letter was input (hence the counters in the menu() method)*/
        System.out.println("You have accessed finalStats()");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I know this is a super long question, but the code is just there IN CASE you want to see it, but my question doesn't require you to look through it all, just understand my question.

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Well, an easy solution to searching through all of the objects in the array is to loop through it.

Example:

```
for (Employee e : arrayOfEmployees) {
  if (e.equals(anotherEmployee)) {
     // do stuff
  } else {
     continue;
  }
}
```

Also, your main method should not be throwing an IOException. Use a try catch statement

Comment: Hi, I don't exactly understand what (Class<?>) means. Would I put the name of my Employee class? and what is the colon used for? Thank You!

Comment: You should really know this before writing complex stuff, which it seems you are doing. What this is called is a for loop. The colon splits the array, into one variable for each class. Class<?> is a class variable. What it seems from your comment, its meant to be your Employee class which I will edit.